# How put JSON data to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, api, vue.js

Im beginner on mongo & javascript, i made a approximate code may be to push all API JSON response on my collection db, so i should take the lead with this code to do something that looks like something rather than doing nothing :

The goal of this [file](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) is convert to a card all result of JSON api response, but before that i need to store this response

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

export const useCardStore = defineStore("cardStore", {
 state: () => ({
  cards: [], 
  }),
  getters:{
     allCards: (state) => state.cards
  },
 actions: {
   async loadCards() {
   try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.adzuna.com/....");
    this.cards = response;
    const { data } = response;
    response.data.results.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      return item.get().then(response => {
        JSON.parse(response.body.text());
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/MyCollection';

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(db) {
        
        var myDB = db.db("JobSeeker");
        
        var myobj = [item];
        
          myDB.collection("cardsJobs").insertMany(myobj, function(res) {
          console.log("Number of item inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
          db.close();
        });
      })
     });
    });
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
      }
  },
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//modify your code like this
var url = "API CALL HERE"

request(url, function(error, response, body){

 if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    res.send(data);

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var myobj = [];
      myobj.push(data);
      db.collection("dabas").insertMany(myobj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
        db.close();
      });
    });
 }
});

//your problem is you passing obj not array
//see below link for your reference
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

Comment: Thank you for u get back, why `url` variable of api need to be same like my mongo adress??

Comment: Well you can use different variable as well, I just wrote it according to my convenience.